# Phabricator's Diffusion cannot find master repo

Tags: git, phabricator

Why would Diffusion not see my git repository's master branch? To the best of my knowledge, everything else about this repo from inside Diffusion seems to work properly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this is a new repo, there is no `master` branch.  Command line Git will automatically create it locally but then you will need to create an initial commit and push the branch:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial Commit."
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. You can see from the Gif that the repository already has 2 commits. Do I have to 'git push -u origin master' anyway?

Comment: That is odd. I wonder where those commits are if not master... What do you get when you type `git branch -a`? Also, you can try to find what branch has those commits by running `git rev-list --remotes` then running a `git log --decorate {commit-hash}`. That info might get you to the source of the problem.

Comment: git branch -a returns '* master'. The git rev-list --remotes command outputs a usage list, so I'm not sure why that didn't work. The log -- decorate command returned (HEAD -> master) for the commits.

Comment: `git branch -a` should return a `remotes/origin/master`  I think something didn't work right with the push. Lets run the `git push -u origin master` command again and see if that makes it any better.

Comment: Interestingly, it errors out saying fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository. fatal: could not read from remote repository. 

I supplied this command as sudo, so it has privilege to execute.